# Simultaneous redirect from (.html to .php) and (http to https) and (non-www to www) using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently editing an existing site to enable https in it.
The website has three requirements for redirect

urls with .html to .php
http to https
non-www to www

The code I am currently using is this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websitename\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websitename.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But when I check www.websitename.com, it is not being redirected to https://www.websitename.com

I am trying many combinations for days (I have only basic knowledge of regexp), but it is showing one deficiency or another. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to https you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```